# After postman GET request is sent, breakpoints in Visual Studio Web API controller are not hit

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api2, postman

Currently I'm sending a `GET` request to a Web API controller method and get a `http 500` response, but none of the breakpoints in the controller code are being hit.

If i move the same code to another controller, the breakpoints are hit.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz3PM.png
[postman parameters][1]

**API**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetOrderParts([FromQuery]UserParams 
userParams)
{
    var orderParts = await _repo.GetOrderParts(userParams);
    Response.AddPagination(orderParts.CurrentPage, orderParts.PageSize,
    orderParts.TotalCount, orderParts.TotalPages);
    return Ok(orderParts);
}
```

Comment: I assume you've rebuilt for debug mode?

Comment: show your code, and Postman request and response parameters